# Spring Data Projections - ClassCastException - Making a projection for an Entity that extends a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

**My theory** is that spring cannot create a Projection for an Entity that extends another class (in my case, this class is DomainObject).

This is my entity (JobEntity): https://pastebin.com/3EdtPBSZ

My repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = JobExcerpt.class)
public interface JobExcerptRepository extends JpaRepository<JobEntity, Long> {
    JobExcerpt findByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);
}
```

JobExcerpt class:

```
@Projection(
        name = "jobProjection",
        types = { JobEntity.class })
public interface JobExcerpt {
    Long getId();

    Long getRetailerId();
}
```

Before you tell me that I have to make my repository #findByIdAndRetailerId method return type "JobEntity", I have tried that and the projection does not get applied, as I am able to access the entity's fields that are not defined in the projection. I am following Baeldung's tutorial combined with some other sources on the net.

**Stack Trace Message**
`java.lang.ClassCastException: au.com.parcelpoint.domain.batch.JobEntity cannot be cast to au.com.parcelpoint.domain.batch.projection.JobExcerpt`

Full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/MjBNTT7Y